# BeautifulSoup: How do I extract the text child element with no tag?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following html to parse. But I am having an issue extracting the Name only.

```
<div class="profile-heading--desktop">
 <h1>
  <span class="profile-heading__rank">
   #1
  </span>
  Jeff Bezos
 </h1>
 <div class="profile-subheading">
  CEO and Founder, Amazon
 </div>
</div>
```

I am having an issue extracting the text for the name, as it is extracting the Rank alongwith it. I want to exclude the Rank showing up with the Name in the following line 2.

```
#1 
#1 Jeff Bezos
CEO and Founder, Amazon
```

The code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.forbes.com/profile/jeff-bezos/?list=forbes-400"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

# Rank
rank = soup.find("span", class_="profile-heading__rank")
print(rank.text)

# Name
name = soup.find("div", class_="profile-heading--desktop").find("span").parent
print(name.text)

# Role
role = soup.find("div", class_="profile-subheading")
print(role.text)
```

Comment: Would it not just be easier to remove the rank with a split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.find_next_sibling()` method with `text=True`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.forbes.com/profile/jeff-bezos/?list=forbes-400"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

# Rank
rank = soup.find("span", class_="profile-heading__rank")
print(rank.text)

# Name
name = rank.find_next_sibling(text=True)    # <-- change
print(name)                                 # <-- .text is not necessary

# Role
role = soup.find("div", class_="profile-subheading")
print(role.text)
```

Prints:

```
#1 
Jeff Bezos
CEO and Founder, Amazon
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `next_sibling` from bs4 to navigate between page elements

```
name = soup.find("div", class_="profile-heading--desktop").find("span").next_sibling
```

docs: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there any reason there is no need to mention `.text` to extract it?

Comment: @Shantanu There is no tags around it so no need to use `.text`